# spring transaction method calls

Tags: java, spring, transactions

Does a transaction method calling a transaction method in the same class cause the transaction to fail.
Will saveAddress be rolled back if an exception occurs after saveAddress is executed.
[transaction invoke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwV2o.png)
The doInsert method is called by another class.

Answer (score 0):

> Does a transaction method calling a transaction method in the same class cause the transaction to fail

No.

> Will saveAddress be rolled back if an exception occurs after saveAddress is executed

Depends on if the transaction has been committed or not. So, if the exception happens *before* `doInsert` returns, yes. If it happens *after* `doInsert` returns, no.

Comment: The Transactional annotation of saveAddress will have no effect at all because it is called from inside the same class.

Comment: thanks @Mar-Z, added that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The transaction will start at the call to `doInsert` method and end on the returning from it. It doesn't matter if local methods will be called inside of this method. You can consider such methods the same way as code blocks inside of the method.

If a runtime exception occurs somewhere inside the transaction it will be rolled back. Otherwise it will be committed.